# How to custom a UITableViewCell like the one in Photo Album app?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage

I'm trying to create a custom UITableViewCell but I have never done so before. I know I am supposed to subclass UITableViewCell but I need more info to start from. I want each cell to display several (2~4) UIImageViews just like is done in the Photo Album app. Has anyone done this before? Or is there a good tutorial that you know of? Please point me in the right direction.

Question: 
**How does one create a custom UITableViewCell similar to the one appearing in the Photo Album app?**